# Generate fields in content from other content values?

Tags: views, nodes

I want to generate fields in a content from the values of other content.

Specifically,  I have a list of "players" stored as a content type, and a separate content type called "Events". Events list the rank of each player that participated. On the "player" content, I'd like to be able to display the players wins by searching all the "events" content. Is this possible?

Also, in Views, is it possible to generate a list of all the events a player has won, as well as how many?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.  On approach is to use the [Entity Reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module.  This allows one field to reference another content type.  With this approach, on your *Event* content type, you could have a field **Winner** that is an entity reference to the player(s) who won.

In Views, you could then easily a list of events a player has won by using a contextual filter to limit the wins displayed to those of the player URL.  You could create a second view and attach it to the first to show how many.

These all require a fair bit of configuration and may be hard to set up at first, but it's definitely possible.